# Neo4j CypherQuery to get nodes with (empty) property

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

Im am wondering if there is a way to get a neo4j node with a (*empty*) property. I defined it as an empty array when I created a the node and update it with data in a seperate query. I am now looking for a way to get the nodes that were never updated. neo4j automatically sets the property to (*empty*) when there is no value in the array. Is there a way to query these nodes? I cannot use the **IS NULL** or **WHERE HAS NOT** query since the property exists. Thanks

**EDIT**
Here is an example of the properties one of the nodes that I am trying to grab. The episodes property is listed as *(empty)*

```
thumbnail:  http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music6/v4/0b/cf/e8/0bcfe8a9-79d4-76c1-645d-5f9b8bb56435/source/100x100bb.jpg
feedUrl:    http://www.iwantspace.com/publicbriefings/?feed=podcast&cat=6
name:   The Audio Collection – SPACE – Public Briefings
episodes:   (empty)
url:    https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/audio-collection-space-public/id367750633?mt=2&uo=4
```

Comment: Perhaps the value is not empty, but actually the string "(empty)"?

Answer (score 3):

So you stored an empty array as a property on the node? Did you try matching on nodes with an empty array for that property?

For example:

```
// Create a node with empty array for property names
CREATE (n:Person) SET n.names = []

MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.names = [] RETURN n
// Returns the node previously created
```

[Here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=8w72i5) is a Neo4j console demonstrating this.

Comment: Beat me to it, I was going to put the exact same answer

Comment: Ive tried that query but the property on the node is not shown as an array. It shows up as _(empty)_. Ive edited my question with an example of one of the nodes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the nodes that don't have the property episodes on them

```
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT HAS(n.episodes) RETURN n;
```

What speaks against episodes being nodes themselves?

Comment: `has` is no longer present in Neo4j, now it is replaced with `exists`